# Next.js 13: Hydration error when conditionally applying initial framer-motion animation value based on screen size

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, framer-motion, next.js13

I am writing an app in Next.js 13 and I use framer-motion for animations. It consists of a single page, split in several screens and navigation happens by scrolling to their section ids. I use the old `pages` directory.

The animation on one of the screens makes the elements slide in from the side when they are scrolled in view. There is a sidebar on bigger screens, but it's hidden on mobile. Because of this, on bigger screens I have to set a different initial X position of the elements, offset to the right, because otherwise they are hidden underneath the sidebar and framer's `whenInView` does not trigger.

I approached this with these pieces of code:

1. A utility function that wraps the browser's `matchMedia` function to provide information for the screen outside of the css files:

```js
export const isMobile = (): boolean => {
   if (typeof window === 'undefined') return false;

   const query = '(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767.98px)';
   const match = window.matchMedia(query);
   return match.matches;
}
```

2. Different values for the element's initial X position, for example:

```
<motion.h1
   initial={{ x: isMobile() ? '93vw' : '86vw' }}
   whileInView={{ x: 0 }}
   transition={{ duration: 0.75, type: 'spring' }}
   viewport={{ once: true }}
   className={classes.element}
>
   Example content
</motion.h1>
```

3. Above all the screens that have dynamic initial values, I added:

```js
'use client';
```

The problem is that I get a hydration error each time I refresh.

```
Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "transform:translateX(86vw) translateZ(0)" Client: "transform:translateX(93vw) translateZ(0)"
```

```
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

The issue seems fairly obvious, but I am not sure how to solve it. I thought that `'use client'` was supposed to leave this component out of server rendering. Or does it only work only in the new `app` directory? Another thing, do you think setting the initial value in an `useEffect` hook could solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I managed to solve it myself. Apparently, framer-motion is smart enough to distinguish client and server when adressing props like style, but in another part of the app I had an entire conditional rendering based on the `isMobile()` function. It would resolve to false on the server, because `window` is undefined, but would be true on the client when using Chrome dev-tools in responsive mode.

Therefore, this piece of code would break the entire thing, despite the error being about something else:

```
const renderLeftSide = (position: GridPosition): JSX.Element | null => {
    if (isMobile()) return null;
    return position === GridPosition.Left ? (
      <TimelineCard position={position} />
    ) : (
      <TimelineDate position={position} />
    );
  };
```

I solved it by creating a client-only wrapper component:

```
const ClientOnly = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [clientReady, setClientReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setClientReady(true);
  }, []);

  return clientReady ? <>{children}</> : null;
};
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!